# How to implement general Erlang server that can become any kind of specific server

Tags: erlang

Currently I'm experimenting with Erlang and would like to implement a kind of universal server (like [this one](https://joearms.github.io/published/2013-11-21-My-favorite-erlang-program.html)) described by Joe Armstrong. The general idea is to create a general server that we can later tell to become a specific one, like this:

```
universal_server() ->
    receive
        {become, F} ->
            F()
    end.
```

And some specific server:

```
factorial_server() ->
    receive
        {From, N} ->
            From ! factorial(N),
            factorial_server()
    end.

factorial(0) -> 1;
factorial(N) -> N * factorial(N-1).
```

And finally send a "become factorial server" message to the universal server:

```
test() ->
    Pid = spawn(fun universal_server/0),
    Pid ! {become, fun factorial_server/0},
    Pid ! {self(), 50},
    receive
        X -> X
    end.
```

What I would like to do is to implement a universal server that can accept multiple subsequent "become" messages (so that I could send a "become factorial server" message and then a "become other kind of specific server" message...).

A naive approach is to require that every specific server implementation will include the `{become, F}` pattern in a `receive` clause. Maybe I could have a behavior that defines the general shape of all specific servers (containing the `{become, F}` clause) and propagates other messages forward to callbacks.

My question is, how to implement such a case in a clean, smart way?

Comment: Instead of calling `F` on `become`, spawn it as another server (let's call it server F). Continue to wait for `become` messages but on any other message pass it along to server F.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is mine:

```
-module(myserver).
-export([start/0, init/0]).


start() ->
    erlang:spawn_link(?MODULE, init, []).


init() ->
    State = undefined, % You may want to do something at startup
    loop(State).
    % if something went wrong comment above line and uncomment below line:
    % exit(element(2, catch loop(State))).


loop(MyState) ->
    Msg =
        receive
            Any ->
                Any
        end,
    handle_message(Msg, MyState).

% We got a message for becoming something:
handle_message({become, Mod, InitArgument}, _) ->
    % Also our callback may want to do something at startup:
    CallbackState = Mod:init(InitArgument),
    loop({Mod, CallbackState});
% We got a message and we have a callback:
handle_message(Other, {Mod, CallbackState}) ->
    case Mod:handle_message(Other, CallbackState) of
        stop ->
            loop(undefined);
        NewCallbackState ->
            loop({Mod, NewCallbackState})
    end;
% We got a message and we Don't have a callback:
handle_message(Other, undefined) ->
    io:format("Don't have any callback for handling ~p~n", [Other]),
    loop(undefined).
```

Also I wrote a simple `counter` program for my server:

```
-module(counter).
-export([init/1, handle_message/2]).


init(Start) ->
    Start.

handle_message(inc, Number) ->
    Number + 1;
handle_message(dec, Number) ->
    Number - 1;
handle_message({From, what_is}, Number) ->
    From ! Number;
handle_message(stop, _) ->
    stop;
handle_message(Other, Number) ->
    io:format("counter got unknown message ~p~n", [Other]),
    Number.
```

Let's test them:

```
Eshell V10.1  (abort with ^G)
1> S = myserver:start().
<0.79.0>

2> S ! hello.
Don't have any callback for handling hello
hello

3> S ! {become, counter, 10}.
{become,counter,10}

4> S ! hi.
counter got unknown message hi
hi

5> S ! inc.
inc
6> S ! dec.
dec
7> S ! dec.
dec

8> S ! {self(), what_is}.
{<0.77.0>,what_is}

9> flush().
Shell got 9
ok

10> S ! stop.             
stop

11> S ! inc.              
Don't have any callback for handling inc
inc
```

#### What should we do to complete it?

As you can see, It's not a production ready code, We should:

- Have a way to set a timeout for initialize.
- Have a way to set process spawn options.
- Have a way to registering process locally or globally or using custom process registries.
- Call callback functions in `try catch`.
- Make sure that a message reply is for current message passing, not for other message that our process sent it before! (what `gen` module provides as `call`).
- Kill ourself when our starter process died and don't be a zombie process if starter is linked to us!
- Call a function at the end for each callback and let them clean those things if they have (you can name it `terminate`).
- Be compatible with OTP `sys` module, So we should defined its callback functions. see [sys callback functions](http://erlang.org/doc/man/sys.html#Module:system_code_change-4). Then we can turn our process to debug mode, see its I/O, change its state in reloading the code, etc.

Note that `proc_lib` and `gen` module can help you to do most of them.